# Derivation of equations for confidence interval of mean of a Poisson distributed variable

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, poisson-distribution, reliability

I'm having trouble understanding why the first equation found in the following Wikipedia link is valid:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Confidence_interval
Can anyone here derive/prove it for me?

I have found something related at Weibull.com, but either they do something wrong or I'm misunderstanding them:
http://www.weibull.com/hotwire/issue116/relbasics116.htm

Also, there are similar equations in MIL-HDBK-338B, page 8-45. Not identical, and no derivation/proof that I find...

Comment: Looks like you need a self study tag.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2427795/relationship-between-chi-square-distribution-and-poisson-distribution ... chances are it's covered in a post somewhere here as well, but I didn't spot it.